# How to debug feathersjs with typescript on VS Code?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, feathersjs

I want to debug a typescript feathersjs project using VSCode but when I launch the program a get the error

> "Cannot launch program '[project_path]/src/index.ts' because
>   corresponding JavaScript cannot be found. "

My launch.json look like this:

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "type": "node",
            "request": "launch",
            "name": "Launch Program",
            "program": "${workspaceFolder}/src/index.ts",
            "preLaunchTask": "tsc: build - tsconfig.json",
            "outFiles": [
                "${workspaceFolder}/lib/**/*.js"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Hah. For some reason, VS Code (latest version) generated it without the "preLaunchTask" line and output that error on my computer. I added that line and now it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The typescript sourceMaps are not being generated.

To fix this problem go to the `tsconfig.json` and add `'"sourceMap": true'` on the `compilerOptions`.

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es2018",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "outDir": "./lib",
    "rootDir": "./src",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "sourceMap": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "test"
  ]
}
```